# Import error when importing rospy when script called through systemd service

Tags: python-3.x, sh, ros, systemd

I am trying to run a python script that uses rospy. Normally when this script is called through command line `python3 npnt_main.py` it runs fine.
But when run through systemd service, I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rospy'
```

The systemd service looks as follows:

```
[Unit]

Description=Npnt Compliance service

[Service]

WorkingDirectory=/srv/maverick/code/maverick/custom-modules/NpntCompliance/catkin_ws/src/npnt_test/

ExecStart=/bin/sh /srv/maverick/code/maverick/custom-modules/NpntCompliance/catkin_ws/src/npnt_test/run/run_npnt.sh &

User=root

Restart=on-failure

RestartSec=3

[Install]

WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The script run_npnt.sh is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# To start npnt_main and handle crashes

BASE="/srv/maverick/code/maverick/custom-modules/NpntCompliance/catkin_ws/src/npnt_test"

echo "Starting npnt"

LOGFILE="$BASE/log/npnt_syslogs.log"
[ -e $LOGFILE ] && rm $LOGFILE > /dev/null 2>&1

echo "Old Logfile: $LOGFILE deleted"

echo "Running npnt"

python3 $BASE/scripts/npnt_main.py > $LOGFILE

ret=$?
if [ $ret -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "npnt_main crashed. Restarting"
fi
```

How can I run it through systemd service without getting an ImportError?